# How to prove $\dim(U)=\dim(W)=\dim(V)-1 \implies V=U+W$ based on the following assumption?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that $\dim(U) =\dim(W)$ and $U\ne W$, how to prove $\dim(U)=\dim(W)=\dim(V)-1 \implies V=U+W$?

My approach is to use $\dim(U+W)=\dim(U)+\dim(W)-\dim(U\cap W)$.

Since $U\ne W$, $\dim(U\cap W)=0$. Now I need to prove that $\dim(U+W)=\dim(V)$.

So $\dim(U+W)=\dim(V)-1+\dim(V)-1+0=2\dim(V)-2$.

But then I don't know how to proceed. Could somebody help?

Comment: Your MathJax code was incredibly messy. I cleaned it up. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

$U \neq W \implies U + 0, 0 + W \subsetneq U + W\subseteq V$. 
Hence $\dim V - 1 = \dim U < \dim (U +W) \leq \dim V$.

Answer (score 0):

$U \neq W$ does not mean $\dim(U\cap W) = 0$. It means $\dim(U\cap W) < \max(\dim(U), \dim(W))$. Here $\dim(U) = \dim(W) = \dim(V) - 1$ thus $\dim(U\cap W) \leqslant \dim(V) - 2$ hence the rest of your reasoning can go well.